# Spring 5 with JUnit 5 + Mockito - Controller method returns null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockito, junit5

I try to test a method named as `loadData` defined in `MainController` which returns result as a string. Despite that this method actually returns data when the web app runs on servlet container (or when I debug the code), no data returns when I invoke it from a test class based on `JUnit 5` with `Mockito`.

**Here is my configuration:**

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppInitializer.class, AppConfig.class, WebConfig.class})
@Transactional
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestMainController {

    @InjectMocks
    private MainController mainController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(this.mainController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoadData() throws Exception {
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/loadData.ajax"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn();

        Assertions.assertNotNull(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), "response should not be null");
    }

}
```

The test fails due to `java.lang.NullPointerException` as the `this.mainController` is `null`.

**Environment Details:**

```
Spring version: 5.0.3
JUnit version: 5.0.3
mockito version: 1.9.5
hamcrest version: 1.3
json-path-assert version: 2.2.0
```

**Edit:** Here is the `loadData` method of `MainController`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadData.ajax", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List list = mainService.loadData(); // starts a transaction and invokes the loadData method of mainDAO repository which basically loads data from the database
    return JSONArray.fromObject(list).toString();
}
```

Comment: You don't call the controller's method directly with MockHttp. You simulate the use of an URL : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html

Comment: Let's say the URL I want to test is `loadData.ajax`. Could you please guide me to setup the test environment? Tried the following through the guide you have shared, but no luck: `mockMvc.perform(get("/loadData.ajax"));`

Comment: Add your `MainController`. What is strange on your test is that you have both a web and regular configuration, shouldn't you have a single one?

Comment: @M.Deinum `AppConfig` is for creating `session factory` and `transaction manager` beans. `WebConfig` implements `WebMvcConfigurer` and defines all the other required beans including `view revolvers`, `interceptors`, `tasks`, etc.

Comment: You don't need to `Autowire` the controller 
You create an instance of `MockMvc` as the following, If the Controller's constructor takes any parameter then you pass them to the controller.
`MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new YourController()).build();`

Comment: @Ali.Wassouf tried that not worked `public class TestMainController {
    @InjectMocks
    private MainController mainController;

    @Mock
    private MainService mainService;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        // Process mock annotations
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MainController()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoadData() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/loadData.ajax")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}`

Comment: As stated please add your `MainController` so that we can see what is happening in there.

Comment: It is **not** possible to declare `@SpringJUnitWebConfig` _and_
`@SpringJUnitConfig` on the same test class. Spring will only honor **one** of them, namely the first one it finds.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your care; the related method definition is added into the post.

Comment: Your test is wrong. You create a mocked controller but don't mock the dependencies or define behavior. You also load the context but don't actually use it.

Comment: So, could you please provide the right one? @M.Deinum

Answer (score 5):

You can call controller method directly, just like we do for service method, but this is not recommended. Using MockMvc, you check for **header** and **request param mapping** are proper. Plus, you also check for **end point mapping** is correct. Plus the **Request METHOD** is also correct. All these you cannot test if you test your code by directly calling the controller method.

One thing you can try is, instead of creating new object inside the standalone context, use the Mock. i.e

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(this. mainController).build();
```

And while calling, do this

```
MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc
    .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/loadData.ajax"))
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn();
```

Assert , what you would like to

```
Assert.assertEquals("response does not match", mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(),
    "some expected response");
```

You are getting null or 400 or 404 http status ?

If you are getting 400, then please check the header and req. param if any are proper. If you are getting 404 then please check the URL path. /loadData.ajax , assuming this is your request mapping path in controller method.

Comment: Getting `NullPointerException` as the `this.mainController` is found as null on the line when the `mockMvc` is initialized.

Comment: Please add **@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)** at class level. Something like this. 

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestMainController {

then you variable mainController will be initialize

Comment: Could not find the `RunWith` class which is a part of `JUnit 4`.

Comment: import org.junit.runner.RunWith;  
i see this under junit:4.12 version. 

and in build.gradle 
 
testCompile("junit:junit:4.12")

Comment: Both JUnit 4 & 5 on the classpath? Does not sound good, as the annotations are defined on the different packages. Getting the exception `No tests found in TestMainController
Haven't you forgot @Test annotation?`

Comment: Really sorry. Forgot you are using Junit5. I have not using JUnit5 with Mockito yet, but a quick search resulted me with this **"In JUnit 5, the RunWith annotation has been replaced by the more powerful ExtendWith annotation."**

may be this will help you http://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-runwith

Comment: no problem but actually `MockitoJUnitRunner` is not compatible with `ExtendWith` annotation.