# NullPointerexception when executing Mock Controller

Tags: mockito

I have below code in my controller class

```
public class GoodsController{

@AutoWired
Private GoodsService goodsService;
public ResponseEntity<String> startCall(HttpServletRequest request) {

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;

        try {
            ResponseBean respBean = goodsService.startCall(request);
            HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

            if(request.getAttribute(SessionConstants.GOODS_SESS) != null){
                responseHeaders.set(SessionConstants.GOODS_SESS,      request.getAttribute(SessionConstants.GOODS_SESS).toString());
            }

            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(SessionUtil.objToJson(respBean, respBean), responseHeaders,
                    HttpStatus.valueOf(respBean.getStatus()));

            return responseEntity;

        } catch (AlightSessionException e) {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("{\"message\": \"error:\""+e.getMessage()+", ")
                    .append("\"status\":\"400\"}");
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(message.toString(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            ErrorLogEventHelper.logErrorEvent(SessionController.class.getName(), message.toString(), "startSessionForPerson()", e,
                    ErrorLogEvent.ERROR_SEVERITY);      
            return responseEntity;
        }

    }
}
```

And I have below code in my TestClass

```
   public class GoodsControllerTest{

    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = 

    MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .post("/startCall").sessionAttr("personToken", "eyjpc");

            ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(request);
             result.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

    }
  }
```

While I am executing I got below error, please help me out.

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>         at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>         at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
>         at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
>         at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
>         at com.alight.upoint.sessionservice.controller.SessionControllerTest.testGetEligiblePlans(SessionControllerTest.java:57)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.alight.upoint.sessionservice.controller.SessionController.startSessionForPerson(SessionController.java:51)
>         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>         ... 17 more

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` to create an application context with just you controller and then use this mockMcv to call your controller API i.e method

You can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891377/spring-unit-testing-rest-controller/48892037#48892037) for more details.